# Inaccurate results from Conversation AI

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, dialogflow-cx, vertex-ai-search

I'm building a chatbot using Vertex AI conversation and Dialogflow CX. for the chatbox the only datastore is a domainset (URLs). Almost everything else is working fine and it is giving relevant information about almost everything, but when it comes to pricing, it does not give even relevant information. I am using the default generative model and Standard NLU with 0.75 threshold.

Earlier it was an image, and since I always want my chatbot to fetch data from my website, I changed it to a table, that didn't work, then I changed to simple short text, for example item (currency unit) - value (unit). I also added the data in a table, but nothing is working for me. This is not an online store. It is a service based company website which has a pricing page and the information is mentioned in according way, not as a product, description, price thing.